# Spring actuator: How to achieve multiple path-mapping

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In my project I have the below snippet in my `application-yaml`

```yaml
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /
      path-mapping:
        health: /v*/ping
```

I would like to map the actuator health endpoint to {domain}/v1/ping, {domain}/v2/ping and so forth.

I discovered the above way myself and wonder if Springboot team has a better idea on it? I have tried regular expression but not work, but I still want more control rather than this wildcard implementation because right now v(anything) will work.

Thank you all!